# Is using sizeof on a variable where a type of the same name exists well defined?

Tags: c, sizeof, undefined-behavior

Is this well defined behaviour or is it undefined / somehow else defined which `foo` (data type or identifier) `sizeof` will be operating on ?

```
typedef int foo;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char foo;
    printf ("%u\r\n", sizeof(foo));
    return 0;
}
```

If it is well defined, is there a way I could obtain the size of the datatype `foo` without declaring a variable of that type only to use `sizeof` on it?

Comment: output will be 1, because `foo` will be taken by `char foo` as it is local variable. Change the name of foo to have global variable scope. And, `int` is `typedef` to `foo`, so size of `foo` should be 4.

Comment: Why would an answer of this have anything to do with `sizeof`?

Comment: @JensGustedt: Pardon me? What are you talking about? It would have to do with `sizeof`, because I faced this scenario while using `sizeof`. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Note that the parenthesis in the expression `sizeof(foo)` apply to `foo`, not `sizeof` and, in this case, are redundant (just like in `return(42);`). The parenthesis are required when `foo` is a type as if you hadn't defined the object `char foo;`

Comment: @pmg I used the parantheses because I was hoping it is using it as indicator for ti to be a type in this case. But thats jsut because, as I allready noted on Potatoswatter answer, that I didnt knew the scope is here crucial.

Comment: @Zaibis, sure you encountered this with `sizeof`. But your real question is: to which entity refers `foo` if there are two `foo`s declared like you have done. Your `sizeof` is just an artifact on how you came to the question, not relevant to the question itself. Your question heading would be of more use for others by removing the words "sizeof on".

Comment: @JensGustedt: You'r right, but when I posted the question it wasn't clear to me that there even strictly defined aspects where my example is jsut one of. And I can't ask a question while respecting knowledge that I just recieved from the answers I got on it. Also just editing the Question would give more Confusion what the answers regarding to then giving any benefit. At all: you are right, sizeof has nothing to do with it. But when I asked the question I wasn't aware of that and thats not a reason IMO to change the whole post.Also dont know how to rephrase the title so it still fits the post.

Comment: FWIW, the GCC warning for this is `-Wshadow`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C does not have explicit scope resolution, so identifiers (variable names, typedef names, struct names, etc etc) can be reused **and overridden** when a new scope is opened. When an identifier is reused, the previous context held by that identifier is no longer *visible*.

In your particular code, the scope of the `typedef` is global, so the typedef is visible everywhere in your compile package. However, you open a new scope with the function declaration, and in that new scope you define a variable that uses the same identifier as the `typedef`. Now, that identifier refers to the variable instead of the type; meaning, until the scope of the variable ends (the end of the function), the `typedef` is completely hidden.

Recall that C is compiled linearly, so you could do something like this as a way around the shielding that occurs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int foo;

int main()
{
    printf ("%zu\n", sizeof (foo)); /* #1 */

    char foo;
    printf ("%zu\n", sizeof foo); /* #2 */

    return 0;
}
```

At point #1, note that the scope of the variable `char foo` has not yet opened since the compiler hasn't reached its declaration. (All the compiler will do is allocate the space on the stack for the variable).

So the usage of `foo` at that point is still in reference to the globally defined `typedef`.

By the time you hit #2, the variable is declared and the lifetime of the variable is formally started, meaning the identifier is now in use for a different entity. It shields the current block scope (started by the function declaration) from the global definition of `foo`.

This is well-document behavior; there is a draft of the C standard up online, but the published standard has to be purchased. The draft says in section 6.2.1:

> If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the
>   inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other entity
>   (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the identifier designates
>   the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the
>   outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope. [source](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Note that this isn't magical or anything...this is all done at compile-time. The compiler has a table of identifiers and the things they reference, and new scopes create new tables for these. It so happens that at point #1 in the code above, the compiler hasn't yet populated the table with the new `char foo` (this is due to the linear compilation). So when it translates the first `printf` line, it looks through all the active scopes to find the identifier `foo`, and sees the `typedef`, and uses that. At the second `printf`, it looks through all the active scopes and finds a more recent use of the identifier `foo` and uses that.

Comment: Your code wouldn't work, though, would it? I thought that in C, variable declarations had to be the first things in functions and other statements were required to come after. (So `char foo;` would have to be the first statement.)

Comment: @Jashaszun Actually, it would only fail in C89, but gcc on my machine compiled it fine in that mode. C99 and C11 will compile this without problems.

Comment: @Jashaszun: I would bet you are working under Windows in the Microsoft Visual Studio IDE. Hence compiling with their compiler your code as Visual C. So for your information. The compiler of MSVC is not conform to the ISO C nor to any other C standard. It is closely related to it but doesn't support all features and is behaving for some situations different to what the C standard is advising. And here you encountered one of this situations. While since c99 it is allowed to declare a variable not just at the beginning of a scope MSVC is still restricted to that rule.

Answer (score 11):

> *Is this well defined behaviour or is it undefined*

This is well defined behaviour.

In your code

```
printf ("%u\r\n", sizeof(foo));
```

`foo` is unambiguous. The *local* or *inner* `foo` "shadows" (or hides) the *outer* `foo`. So, it is essentially

```
printf ("%u\r\n", sizeof(char));
```

To quote `C11`, chapter §6.2.1, "Scopes of identifiers", (*emphasis mine*)

> If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). **Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**

Now, to answer the second part,

> *If it is well defined, is there a way I could obtain the size of the datatype `foo` without declaring a variable of that type to only use `sizeof` on it?*

Well, a scope of the *inner* `foo` identifier starts *after* it's definition (as a `char` type variable). So, if you use `foo` (the `typedef`ed type) *before* the definition of variable `foo`, you'll be actually *seeing* the global definition, as till that point , variable `foo` is not present to "shadow out" the global identifier `foo`.

As mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31425267/2173917) by [Mr. Purag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814761/purag), you can surely do something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int foo;

int main(void)
{
    printf ("%zu\n", sizeof foo); /* will cosider the global */
    char foo = 0;                 /* Global definition gets shadowed here*/
    printf ("%zu\n", sizeof foo); /* The local definition of 'foo' is only visible*/ 
                                  /* till the end of the block (function)*/

    return 0;
}
```

---

That said, as a note, the type of the result of `sizeof` operator is `size_t`. You should be using `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

Comment: Your answer made it for me, but after Purag had such a awsome explanation and served a workaround, his answer is the one that has to be accepted.

Comment: @Zaibis Whatever you think is best, choose that one. I also agree the answer you're ticking is great. :-)

Answer (score 6):

The local `char foo` completely hides `typedef int foo` in its scope. You cannot observe the name `foo` once it is hidden. Try creating a second `typedef foo foo_t`, or renaming something to avoid the "collision."

Comment: Can you give me a refference that explains why it is hiding it? (orefered a standard C refference.)

Comment: @Zaibis This is a known behavior. You can reuse identifiers within new scopes, and the function opens a new scope.

Comment: @Zaibis Do you really need that? This is how names work in the C family of languages, and most other programming languages. Local name declarations overlay the set of declarations visible from outer scopes.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: And I never heared of this. Thats why I really would like to have that, because it feels currently to me there is something important I never heared of and don't take it personal, but if something happens to me I like to obtain that knowledge about it from a primary source.

Comment: Note: It is not that I'm not beliving you, it is just when I'm facing something new I dont want to risk to missunderstand it.

Comment: @Zaibis No worries, I'm the same way.

Answer (score 2):

First of all according to the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size
>   is determined from the type of the operand.** The result is an
>   integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type,
>   the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and
>   the result is an integer constant.

Thus it is the type of the operand of the sizeof operator that determinates the size of the operand. So you may use interchangeably either an expression or some type definition.

Take into account that an expression used in the sizeof operator is not evaluated.

For example you can write

```
int x = 10;
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( ++x ) );
```

and after the printf x will have the same value 10 as before the printf.

As for your code snippet it seems that you made a mistake. I think you mean the following

```
typedef int foo;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo exp;
    printf ("%zu\r\n", sizeof( exp ));
    return 0;
}
```

Of course there is no need to create an object of type foo. You could write simply

```
    printf ("%zu\r\n", sizeof( foo ));
```

As for your original code

```
typedef int foo;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char foo;
    printf ("%u\r\n", sizeof(foo));
    return 0;
}
```

then identifier name `foo` in the block scope of function main hides the type definition `foo` in the global scope and statement

```
    printf ("%u\r\n", sizeof(foo));
```

is equivalent to

```
    printf ("%u\r\n", sizeof( char ));
```

In C you can't refer to the global definition of foo in this case.