# Why does the malloc order matter when a struct is sufficiently sized?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I ran into an interesting problem today. This snippet prints garbage (e.g. `?Y@??`):

```c
typedef struct {
    int field_1;
    int field_2;
    int field_3;

    char *arr[64];
} test;

int main(void) {
    test *test = malloc(sizeof(test));
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
    strncpy(str, "hello", 5);
    str[5] = '\0';
    test->arr[0] = str;

    printf("%s\n", test->arr[0]);
}
```

However, changing `test` to:

```c
typedef struct {
    int field_1;
    int field_2;

    char *arr[64];
} test;
```

(removing `field_3`) prints the expected result (`hello`).

Even stranger, swapping the `malloc` calls like so:

```c
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
test *test = malloc(sizeof(test));
```

prints the correct result regardless of the size of `test`.

What the heck is going on here?

I'm using `clang-1200.0.31.1`.

Comment: `test = malloc(sizeof(test));` --> `test = malloc(sizeof *test);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
test *test = malloc(sizeof(test));
```

Here, `sizeof(test)` is referring to the variable named `test`, not the type named `test`.  So you're getting the size of a pointer, not the size of the struct.  As a result, you're not allocating enough space for the object in question and you write past the end of allocated memory, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Give either the typedef or the variable a different name, for example:

```
typedef struct {
    int field_1;
    int field_2;
    int field_3;

    char *arr[64];
} test_type;

...

test_type *test = malloc(sizeof(test_type));
```

Comment: This explains why my other computer got different results; the compiler revisions were different. The other computer must have been tokenizing that `test` differently.

Comment: @atirit It probably tokenized the same.  Once you write into memory you shouldn't, there are no guarantees.  The program may crash or it may appear to work properly then mysteriously break later.

Comment: The other was getting correct results 100% of the time, and I was only getting correct results one in a few hundred tries. The other one was `clang-900.0.26`, so it's feasible that within three major version changes, the tokenizer started to interpret this case differently. However, it's also possible that the other computer was lucky.

Comment: @atirit Tokenization is dictated by the C standard.  That wouldn't have changed.  Just because it always appeared to work on one system doesn't mean it was correct.  Had you modified the program to perform additional operations you would have eventually seen unexpected results.

Comment: "Dictated by the C standard" In that case, you're definitely right.

Comment: Interesting that clang doesn't seem to be able to give a warning about this.  Not even with `-Weverything`.  Nor does gcc.  It seems like that would be useful.

Comment: Ah, I see the well-definedness was previously addressed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424504/is-using-sizeof-on-a-variable-where-a-type-of-the-same-name-exists-well-defined.

Comment: I would rather use objects instead of types `test_type *test = malloc(sizeof(*test));`